# exec() function not working in PHP

Tags: php, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a php file which executes a batch file which in turn creates a scheduled task. It doen't work. I double checked to make sure that safe mode is OFF. Here is my code,

```
$output = array();

exec("C:/wamp/www/ESReminders/createScheduleTask.bat",$output);
```

I also tried,

```
exec("c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:/wamp/www/ESReminders/createScheduleTask.bat",$output);
```

Batch File Code:

```
schtasks /delete /tn "textReminders" /f
schtasks /create /tn "textReminders" /tr "C:/wamp/www/ESReminders/textReminders.bat" /sc DAILY /st 01:00:00
```

---

The $output shows,

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => C:\wamp\www\ESReminders>schtasks /delete /tn "textReminders" /f [2] => [3] => C:\wamp\www\ESReminders>schtasks /create /tn "textReminders" /tr "C:/wamp/www/ESReminders/textReminders.bat" /sc DAILY /st 01:00:00 )
```

Now since the $output array is filled with lines from my batch file, i am assuming that `exec()` function worked but it doesn't create the schedule task though. If I run the batch file manually, it works fine. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Did you check your PHP `error_log`?

Comment: The Apache Error log shows, "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done."